# How to filter a groupby sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to total sections of a total column using the groupby function. When I use the groupby function 'code' it works however I would like to be able to filter it down to one nominal code by placing it in a variable and printing it.

```
subheading_one = df.groupby(['Code'])['Total'].sum()
subheading_two = df.groupby(['Code'])['Total'].sum()
subheading_three = df.groupby(['Code'])['Total'].sum()

print('Cost heading 1.1 £: ',subheading_one)
print('Cost heading 1.2 £: 'subheading_two)
print('Cost heading 1.3 £: 'subheading_three)
```

I have attached a snippet of the data frame. As you can see I would like to be able to total only '1.1' items and place that total into a variable (should equal 300). Can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get_group` like this

```
subheading_one = df.groupby(['Code'])['Total'].get_group('1.1').sum()
```

I am assuming your Code feature has string values.

Comment: I get 'KeyError: '1.1'.  Is it not possible to have the labels in my 'code' column as 1.1, 1.2 etc.? Is this why I get an error?

Comment: Try it without the string '1.1' and use 1.1.

Comment: @planckepoch86 The answer above is better. It does the calculation of grouping only once. You do it 3 times with my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to perform the `.groupby` operation once, and then use `.loc` to select the specific total you want:

```py
totals = df.groupby(['Code'])['Total'].sum()

print('Cost heading 1.1 £: ', totals.loc['1.1'])
print('Cost heading 1.2 £: ', totals.loc['1.2'])
```

---

edit:
If your code column are floats (not strings), you can do:

```py
totals = df.groupby(['Code'])['Total'].sum()

print('Cost heading 1.1 £: ', totals.loc[1.1])
print('Cost heading 1.2 £: ', totals.loc[1.2])
```

Comment: This is a more efficient solution.

Comment: As above replies I also get the keyerror with this method as well? Any help massively appreciated. I forgot to note that the dataframe is pulling from a CSV.

Comment: Don't use a string in .loc['1.1']. It should be .loc[1.1]. Nice answer though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    code = {'Code': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(code)
    df['Description'] = 'Item here'
    df['Quantity'] = 1
    df['Unit'] = 'Item'
    df['Rate'] = 100
    df['Total'] = 100

    mask = df['Code'] == 1.1
    subheading_one = df.loc[mask, 'Total'].sum()
    mask = df['Code'] == 1.2
    subheading_two = df.loc[mask, 'Total'].sum()
    mask = df['Code'] == 1.3
    subheading_three = df.loc[mask, 'Total'].sum()

    print(f'Cost heading 1.1 £: {subheading_one}')
    print(f'Cost heading 1.2 £: {subheading_two}')
    print(f'Cost heading 1.3 £: {subheading_three}')
```